# Suppress Gradle deprecation warnings

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After migrating a Gradle-based project to Gradle version 4.0-rc-1 some deprecation warnings are displayed in the build output. Because the deprecated methods are used by Gradle plugins I have no control over fixing the warnings. The Gradle documentation and help have no information about disabling such warnings.

*How can Gradle deprecation warnings be suppressed?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is option `--warning-mode none` for suppressing deprecation warnings.

Comment: Where do I put it?

Comment: @Andrei Add org.gradle.warning.mode=none to gradle.properties

Answer (score 0):

To suppress Kotlin compiler warnings you can add the following configuration to `build.gradle.kts`:

```
tasks {
    withType<KotlinCompile> {
        compilerOptions.suppressWarnings = true
    }
}
```